# How to disable some Zend View Helpers

Tags: zend-framework, helper, bootstrapping, view-helpers, zend-view

I'm trying to make a way to disable some view helpers that are inside "application/views/helpers"...

What I really want is to put some options on the application.ini to enable or disable some Helpers.

**Example on application.ini:**

```
helpers.Helper1=on
helpers.Helper2=off
```

Now the problem is that when a Helper is off, I want to rewrite some functions of this helper in order to return a different result on the view. In this way, I don't need to change anything in the view script.

I thought in having 2 different php files for each helper, in different locations. One with the real helper and another with the changed helper (to work when it is off on the application.ini).

The problem is that I don't know how to tell the view which one it shoul load...

Does anyone know how it could be done?

**FINAL CODE**

Ok, after many tries, I put it to work with the following code:

**Bootstrap**

```
protected function _initConfigureHelpers(){
    $this->bootstrap('view');
    $view = $this->getResource('view');

    $view->addHelperPath("./../library/ConfigHelpers","Configurable_Helper");
    $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper(
        'ViewRenderer'
    );
    $viewRenderer->setView($view);
    $front  = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $front->registerPlugin(new Application_Plugin_ViewPlugins());
    return $view;
}
```

**Application_Plugin_ViewPlugins**

```
class Application_Plugin_ViewPlugins extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{

    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request){

        $front=Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $bootstrap=$front->getParam('bootstrap');
        $options=$bootstrap->getOption("helpers");
        if (is_array($options)){
            $view = $bootstrap->getResource('view');

            foreach($options as $option => $value){
                $helper=$view->getHelper($option);
                if ($helper){
                    if ($value=="off")
                        $helper->__disable();
                    else if ($value!="on")
                        throw new Exception('The value of helpers.'.$option.' must be "on" or "off" on application.ini.');
                } else {
                    throw new Exception("Inexistent Helper");
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Modified helper example**

```
require_once APPLICATION_HELPERS."CssCrush.php";

class Configurable_Helper_CssCrush extends Zend_View_Helper_CssCrush {

    protected $__config_enabled = true;

    public function __disable(){
        $this->__config_enabled = false;
        return $this;
    }


    public function __enable(){
        $this->__config_enabled = true;
        return $this;
    }

    public function cssCrush(){
        if ($this->__config_enabled){
            return parent::cssCrush();
        } else{
            return new Modified_CssCrush();
        }
    }

}

class Modified_CssCrush {

    public static function file ( $file, $options = null ) {
        return $file;
    }

}
```

APPLICATION_HELPERS is defined on /public/index.php as "../application/views/helpers/".

Now, when I want to add a configurable helper, I put the original helper on "/application/views/helpers/" and then, create a modified version of it on "/library/ConfigHelpers" with the structure of the example above.

Comment: It looks a little messy, but if it works it works. As you become more familiar with how zf works you'll notice areas that can be improved. e.g. if you're using zf default autoloading the `require_once APPLICATION_HELPERS."CssCrush.php";` statement at the top of your helper file shouldn't be needed at all.

Comment: Also, your paths, though they work, are probably going to cause you problems later; if "library/" is on your include_path then I think you can change the *hardcoded* ConfigHelpers view path to `$view->addHelperPath("ConfigHelpers/Configurable/Helper", "ConfigHelpers_Configurable_Helper");` and rename `Configurable_Helper_CssCrush` to `ConfigHelpers_Configurable_Helper_CssCrush`. You can go shorter again  `$view->addHelperPath("ConfigHelpers/Helper","ConfigHelpers_Helper");` and `ConfigHelpers_Helper_CssCrush` Read up on autoloading http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.autoloading.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you want is [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) which is coming in [zf2](http://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/zend.di.html), but not available in zf1.

With some tinkering though you can get what you need.

### Configuring helpers in the bootstrap

*(assumes default project structure)*

View helpers paths config : application/configs/application.ini:

```
resources.view.helperPath.Zf_View_Helper_ = "Zf/View/Helper"
```

A simple configurable helper, *(allows disable/enable but you can obviously add any methods you need (use this as base class for helpers that need the behaviour)*

```
class Zf_View_Helper_Configurable extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    protected $isEnabled = true;

    public function configurable()
    {
        return $this;
    }

    public function disable()
    {
        $this->isEnabled = false;
        return $this;
    }


    public function enable()
    {
        $this->isEnabled = true;
        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        if ($this->isEnabled) {
            return 'Configurable is enabled';
        } else {
            return 'Configurable is disabled';
        }
    }
}
```

And configure the helpers in the bootstrap:

```
public function _initConfigureHelpers()
{
    $this->bootstrap('view');
    $view = $this->getResource('view');

    $configurableHelper = $view->configurable();
    $configurableHelper->disable();
}
```

You can add options in the .ini file and grab them in the bootstrap initConfigureHelpers() method.

If you want this behaviour from any default zf helper, do what @Ratzo said and extend those helpers and add the required behaviour and then configure them in your bootstrap.

Comment: So, do I need to put the enable and disable functions on all my extending helpers or is there a way to define them just once and then "import" them in the extended helpers?

Comment: You only need to define the methods in the configurable helper. All other helpers can extend it, so they will inherit the same behaviour. So say you have a new helper called `Zf_View_Helper_HelloWorld` and you want it to be configurable, then you will extend the configurable helper: `class Zf_View_Helper_HelloWorld extends Zf_View_Helper_Configurable { ... }`.

Comment: If you mean the default zf helpers, then probably yes, you will need to define your enable/disable in all those extending helper classes. Unless you're on php5.4, in which case you can take advantage of traits: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php.

Comment: So, I need to change all the functions that I want, inside the configurable helper? If so, what if I have this code on the view: `$this->minifyHeadScript()->appendFile("some_js.js");`?

Comment: Yes. Your minifyHeadScript helper is a custom one, great! Just have your minifyHeadScript helper extend the configurable one and that's it, you'll be able to enable and disable it. In your configurable helper overide the __toString() for the desired output depending on enabled or disabled. In other words, you will have something like: if enabled call `return parent::__toString()` else return something else.

Comment: Hmm, but I would like to not change the default code of the minifyHeadScript helper, because it have copyrights. I would prefer to have a specific "configurable helper" for each helper, located in another folder. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the following link [Zend_View link](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html)

Below is an important points you should consider from the Zend docs.

> Note: Default Helper Path
>
> The default helper path always points to the Zend Framework view
>   helpers, i.e., 'Zend/View/Helper/'. Even if you call setHelperPath()
>   to overwrite the existing paths, this path will be set to ensure the
>   default helpers work.

This means that you can't really turn off the helpers, unless you want to go about extending the Zend_View object and overwrite the setHelperPath method. This is not the way to go though.

Here is probably what you want to do. First though, here is my assumption.

Assumption : You want to write your own view helper that slightly alters what the current view helpers do by changing a few methods here or there.

Here is what you should do to accomplish that.

First, write your view helper. Make sure the last part of the class name is the same as the view helper you want to 'overwrite'. You don't have to, but this makes sure the original helper can't be used anymore.

```
class My_View_Helper_BaseUrl extends Zend_View_Helper_BaseUrl

{   
    private $_enabled = true;
    public function setEnabled( $bool ){ $this->_enabled = (boolean) $bool; }
    public function baseUrl(){ 
        if( $this->_enabled ){
             return 'testUrl'; //other code 
        }
        else return parent::baseUrl();
}
```

Now that you have that, do the following

```
$view->setHelperPath('/path/to/my/helpers', 'My_View_Helper'); //1
echo $view->baseUrl();  //2
```

Excellent. Now you've effectively shadowed the original BaseUrl helper.
The above code will make it so that the view scans your directory
for any helpers before scanning the default zend directory. When it gets to line 
2 the view will find YOUR baseUrl helper first and use THAT instead of the 
original baseUrl helper. In the above example it should echo
'testurl' instead of the normal baseUrl behavior.

Comment: Ok, but I want to use that like @BullfrogBlues said. In other words, I want to have a variable that controls what some functions of the helper should return when the variable is put to true or false. The problem is that my helpers are in the "application/views/helpers" and when I do an "extends Zend_View_Helper_MinifyHeadScript" (for example), it doesn't find "Zend_View_Helper_MinifyHeadScript"...

Comment: If you want to use the original helper, then you can eliminate line one at the end there. It'll find the normal zend helper in that case.

Or you can make the changes that I added in the edit.

Comment: You can add the enabled/unenabled methods to a base class. This is a variant of what BullfrogBlues is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom helper that extends the original helper, for example

```
class My_Helper_Url extends Zend_View_Helper_Url
{}
```

and rewrite the methods as you need.